# Theoretically basic RDLC groups and supgrouping 

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I'm trying to do something that I thought ought to be reasonably simple but I keep failing... Maybe I just need more coffee, but I thoguht i see if anyone else has solved the problem already.

I've got a report, it contains a pile off rows.

1. I want the row to show up grouped by one column called office.
2. I want the groups of offices sorted by their column region.
3. I want the rows within the office group sorted by column name.

so it'd show up like this

```
Region1
 Agency a
  a
  b
  c
 Agency b
  a
  b
Region 2
 Agency a1
  a
  b
  c
```

etc...

I can get the grouping, I can get the groups sorted by region.

but I can't get the contents of the group to be sorted by name.

my curret guess was Group by Office
then in the sort tab, sort by region, then office, then name. no joy.

Any help is appreciated.

if it's relavant I'm using c# and vs2008.

Thanks,

E-

Comment: You might want to reformat your results using <pre> </pre> tag to look more readable.

Comment: You also might want to change the title to reflect the subject of your question. Removing modifiers, the title currently reads "Question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often have problems with sorting in the rdl/rdlc and end up having to sort the data that is coming to the report to get it to show up correct.  Also sometimes it helps if you add sorting on every group.  So for your Region group you'd add all the sorting.  Then on the Office Group also add sorting.

Comment: this works, also you can put the sorting on the group and the table and for some reason it works too.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the sort in the table, it worked for me

Comment: yeah I wound up having to put the sorting in every group and the tables both to get consistant sorting.